# NSJSONSerialization returning null

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I am writing an app which is supposed to read JSON data from a remote web service. the URL is in the format "something.action".

I use dataWithContentsofURL to download the JSOn data from the service and I see that this function does return back some data.

Using this data I call the function NSJSONSeraiization, but the response of this is null.

Basically, I am using the code provided on http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5. The only difference is that I am fetching data from a remote server and my URL is of the form "something.action".

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: What does your returned data look like? If you interpret it as a string (using `[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]`), does it look like JSON?

Comment: The variable data which is created by using dataWithContentsofURL does return some hexadecimal values, but when I use the command given by you in the above comment, it is returning Null. Any clue what is going wrong here?

Comment: The encoding used is simply wrong. The data you received is probably not in UTF8 encoding as I supposed but in any other encoding (you have to check with the developer of the webservice or the service doc to know which encoding it used)

Answer (score 1):

Check a JSON viewer like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to confirm if the JSON returned is correct or not.

Do an NSLog of the string obtained from the NSData you receive and use it with the viewer. If there are any issues, you know why the object is not serialized.

Comment: The data that I am getting is not in the proper format, it is random strings like 6d70616e. 

1. Data is what I get from NSDATA by using the function dataWithContentsOfURL. The class of this function is showing as NSConcreteData

2. The class of the data by using NSJSONSerialization is coming up a null :(

Comment: Can you convert the NSData into a string and check what the response is?

Answer (score 0):

Check the response you get is a properly-formatted JSON file, if it is check its class:

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSJSONSerialization *myJSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theNSDataObained options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

if(jsonError != nil){
    NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", jsonError);
    return;
}

//An NSJSONSerialization object will either be an NSDictionary or 
//an NSArray, figure out what it is: 

NSLog(@"JSON class is: %@", [myJSONObject class]);

//if it's a NSDictionary:
if([myJSONObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    NSDictionary *myJSONDictionary = (NSDictionary *) myJSONObject;
    for(id key in myJSONDictionary){
        id value = [myJSONDictionary valueForKey:key];
        [value doStuff];
    }
} 
else //if it's a NSArray....
```

Comment: The class of 'theNSDataObtained' is showing up as NSConcreteData and that of myJSONObject is coming up as null.

one more thing (if it matters)... when I try to use an internet link to download and display the data, it is coming up properly. But in my case, the data is available on an internal enterprise server.